# Camera Issue in SamSung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, android-camera

I am capturing Image and its showing pretty well in others device but When I clicked on Samsung Galaxy S4, its not showing in ReyclerView but its holding placeholder. I want to show my preview for Clicked Image.. What I had done , it is below.

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        try {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToLast();

                img_Decodable_Str = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

                stream_imagePath.add(img_Decodable_Str);
                CreateStreamAdapter createStreamAdapter = new CreateStreamAdapter(getApplicationContext(), stream_imagePath);
                recycler_view.setAdapter(createStreamAdapter);
                createStreamAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few modifications, Finally, I got my output.

What I did is here,

Firstly, I am storing my data into BUndle by Overriding onSaveInstanceStatelike below

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArrayList("savedList", stream_imagePath);
    System.out.println("On Saved Called ");
    Log.d("SAVED ", "onSaveInstanceState: ");
}
```

And now, after capturing it, I am getting all those images from ArrayList

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_create_stream, null);
    setContentView(v);
    activity = CreateStreamActivity.this;
    init(v);


    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        stream_imagePath = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("savedList");
        createStreamAdapter = new CreateStreamAdapter(getApplicationContext(), stream_imagePath);
        recycler_view.setAdapter(createStreamAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
   Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                pic = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "image name") + ".jpg");

                picUri = Uri.fromFile(pic);

                cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);

                cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, PHOTO);
```

Comment: Thnxx for your reply but let me know what is mApp.getPreference

Comment: That is what i had used for saving the image into external disk by image name as user name